# How to reference a column from inside WITH clause, grabbed with star, in the outside section?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I use star inside the WITH clause and then reference columns on the outside query?

The following query does not work (ORA-00904: "MAINQ"."PARTITION_ID": invalid identifier) :

```
with mainq as (
 select * 
  from table1 s1
  left outer join table2 s2
   on s1.id = s2.id
   and s1.partition_id = s2.partition_id
)
select partition_id from mainq;
```

I do not want to specify the columns in the WITH section because there are many of them, so it would be more useful for me to just grab all.

Comment: "it would be more useful for me to just grab all." - maybe so, but you have two tables and they both have a `partition_id` column - which means that there are two columns with the same name if `select *` works. It's a bad habit to get into of using `select *` anywhere outside of ad-hoc queries and `EXISTS()` checks.

Comment: but one is called partition_id and the other is called partition_id_1

Comment: if both have same columns then that won't work,if you have idea about columns which are same,you can try s1.*,s2.name as somename....

Comment: @Belun - I believe *but could be completely wrong* that that's how they're *displayed* by your querying tool in certain circumstances but their names within a result set would be identical.

Comment: The Query Result grid does add the `_1`; if you just run the inner query, or do `select *` from the full query as a script, then you can see the column names are the same - you can also see that via dbms_sql or dbms_xmlgen. But given that, it's interesting that this gets ORA-00904 rather then ORA-00918. The same happens with a subquery instead of a CTE. But it does switch to ORA-00918 if you change to `select s1.*, s2.*` in the inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a little edit to your query, maintaining the same meaning:

```
with mainq as (
 select * 
  from table1 s1
  left outer join table2 s2
   using(id, partition_id)
)
select partition_id from mainq;
```

This will tell Orale to do the same join as yours, but giving only one occurrence of the columns in the join conditions.

For example:

```
insert into table1 values (1, 2);
insert into table2 values (1, 2);

SQL> select *
  2    from table1 s1
  3    left outer join table2 s2
  4     using(id, partition_id);

        ID PARTITION_ID
---------- ------------
         1            2

SQL> select *
  2    from table1 s1
  3    left outer join table2 s2
  4     on s1.id = s2.id
  5     and s1.partition_id = s2.partition_id;

        ID PARTITION_ID         ID PARTITION_ID
---------- ------------ ---------- ------------
         1            2          1            2
```

Comment: very elegant : http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljusing.html#rrefsqljusing (the only downfall : "the columns listed in the USING clause must be present in both of the two tables being joined", but still...)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if id and partition_id are the only common columns of the two tables, you have this possibility:

```
with mainq as (
 select * 
  from table1 s1
  natural left join table2 s2
)
select partition_id from mainq;
```

(read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BABBAGAH))

However I strongly discourage you from using this syntax. It's much better to be explicit about your joins and columns.

Comment: no, that is not the case, i just use only 2 columns for simplification

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
with mainq as (
 select s1.* 
  from table1 s1
  left outer join table2 s2
   on s1.id = s2.id
   and s1.partition_id = s2.partition_id
)
select partition_id from mainq;
```

Because you have partition_id column twice , both s1 and s2 too. So you can use my script.